# Making border appear at the top

Tags: html, css

I wrote code to make border appear at the top of the website but the border appears on all 4 sides of the code. Please correct me. **[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jpo80bjr/)**.

```css
#box1{
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#DFE4E6;
    padding: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top: thick single #000;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
       <h3 class="center"> CALL US</h3>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because of:

1. the rule `border-style: solid`.

Remove that:

```
border-style: solid;           /* -- remove this */
border-top: thick solid #000;  /* make the style solid here */
```

`border-style` applies to all borders. You need to keep your style limited to `border-top`.

2. `single` is not a style. You probably meant `solid` here.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jpo80bjr/3/

```css
#box1{
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#DFE4E6;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: thick solid #000;
}
.center{ text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div id="box1">
       <h3 class="center"> CALL US</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to define the other borders to 0px, like:

```css
#box1{
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#DFE4E6;
    padding: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top: thick single #000;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
       <h3 class="center"> CALL US</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can *either* write three separate properties:

```
border-width: ..;
border-style: ..;
border-color: ..;
```

*Or* you can combine them into one shorthand property:

```
border: .. .. ..;
```

`border-style` is equivalent to setting the style in `border`, it applies to all sides. If you just want to set the *top* border style, there's `border-top-style` for that. But since you're setting the `border-top` shorthand property anyway, **just get rid of `border-style`.**

Answer (score 2):

That's because you set `border-style: solid;` which applies to all four borders (top, right, bottom, left) and defaults to black and ~4px. Also, single isn't a valid border value.

Try this:

```
#box1{
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#DFE4E6;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: thick solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `border-style: solid;` to `border-top-style: solid;`

**[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jpo80bjr/2/)**

```css
#box1
{
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#DFE4E6;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top: thick single #000;
}
.center
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
    <h3 class="center">CALL US</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

fix your css. some browser auto complete css proporties you did not specify, based on those you did, like border, in your case:

```css
#box1{
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#DFE4E6;
    padding: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: thick 0 0 0;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
       <h3 class="center"> CALL US</h3>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove border-style: solid; because you are already using in border-top: thick solid #000; and single needs to be solid.
use css:

```
#box1{
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#DFE4E6;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: thick solid #000;
}
```

find **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jpo80bjr/5/)**